# plotting patch variable against depth in netlogo

Tags: plot, netlogo

I am having an issue with plotting a particular variable of my program, light, against the ycor at which the light shines, depth. The light varies due to the turtles in my program but also due to how far a patch is from the "sun." Can anyone think of a solid plan on how to make this plot? My code for the plot thus far is:

```
to light-depth-plot 
  let a (list light)
   (foreach a [plotxy ?1 ycor]) 
end
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you.